# Rails - Data model complex relationship between entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model

I am writing a piece of software in Rails.  Two relationships between models has my head spinning on where attributes should reside.  It's an atypical pricing scenario involving prices of products sold to certain customers.  Our Products may be sold at different prices depending on the customer. Some of the bigger companies we sell to have negotiated our prices down a bit.

```
General Pricing Applicable to most customers
  Product A -> $50
  Product B -> $60
  Product C -> $70
```

Therefore it would be easy in this case to say that a Product has a price attribute.  However, the company has negotiated prices with a few big time customers where the following may occur.

```
ACME Corporation
  Product A -> $45
  Product B -> $56
  Product C -> $64

ABC Incorporated
  Product A -> $43
  Product B -> $55
  Product C -> $66
```

These prices are negotiated and not based on some discount percentage off the original price.  This introduces the problem that each product can have many prices depending on the customer.  How do I model this.  under most use cases the following works.

```
Customer has_many :quotes
Quote belongs_to :customer

Quote has_many :quote_items
QuoteItem belongs_to :quote

Product has_many :quote_items
QuoteItem belongs_to :product
```

But since the price of a product can be different depending on the customer, how is this modeled? Is a product a many to many relationship with Customer for example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the infrastructure is laid out, but here is an idea.

```
Customer has_many :products
Product belongs_to :customer
```

And just go to the Product model and create a "quote" attribute.

Then you could do for example

```
ACME.ProductA.quote
=> $45
```

EDIT (adding more)

Hm, you would have to elaborate... As it is, if you want to get inventory -say- all instances of productA, just do something like (conceptually)

```
listOfProducts = Product.find_by_<name>("productA") 

for each productA from listOfProducts 
  print productA.quote
```

If you wanted to further get the customer of the product, you could track the ID of the customer through URL parsing

Comment: This idea would create a lot of duplicate records.  If in the future, I wanted to track inventory,  I may have 5 separate table entries for the same product.  The product should have one record in the product table.

Comment: I'm assuming each customer has a unique price for each of their products.

Comment: It's not their products.  It's our products that are priced differently for each customer.  ProductA may be sold to CustomerA at $55, CustomerB at $45.

Comment: Hm, you would have to elaborate...
As it is, if you want to get inventory -say- all instances of productA, just do something like (conceptually) 

listOfProducts = Product.find_by_<name>("productA")

for each productA from listOfProducts
print productA.quote

If you wanted to further get the customer of the product, you could track the ID of the customer through URL parsing

Comment: your answer is hacking at best.  To demonstrate.  If a product has 20 attributes, your solution is to duplicate 19 of them for each customer I have different pricing for.  If I have 20 customers that's 380 attributes I have to input.  The only data that needs additional tracking is the price attribute.  It seems like a waste to input descriptions, names, item codes etc every time I negotiate a non standard price for one of my low margin high revenue customers.  That's what I mean by duplication.

Comment: I down voted you on your answer's merit, not because I was upset.  Can't say the same for you.

Comment: alright then. I'll take it back if it bugs you so. I just tried to give some input to help out, but I don't think it was appreciated. glhf

Comment: It was appreciated but invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is a many to many relationship between products and customers and utilize a lookup table named product_customers to track the price attribute.  Not sure if this is the most elegant method, but it keeps duplication to a minimum.  The drawback is the additional complexity in handling forms.  If anyone come up with a more elegant answer, I'll give them the points.

```
Customer has_many :products, :through => :customer_products
Customer has_many :customer_products
Customer has_many :quotes
Quote belongs_to :customer

Product has_many :customers, :through => :customer_products
Product has_many :customer_products
Product has_many :quote_items
QuoteItem belongs_to :product

CustomerProducts belongs_to :customers
CustomerProducts belongs_to :products

Quote has_many :quote_items
QuoteItem belongs_to :quote
```